# This integral/ complex algebra seems way too complicated.

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, physics

I'm trying to find this integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Psi^*(x,t)\left(-\hbar^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\right)\Psi(x,t)\ dx$$

where $$\Psi(x,t) = \frac{e^{-x^2/4(a^2+i\hbar t/2m)}}{\sqrt[4]{2\pi}\sqrt{a+i\hbar t/2ma}}$$

I'm reasonably certain that I calculated this wave function $\Psi$ correctly because the square of its absolute value is a Gaussian distribution which evolves in time which I know is what it's supposed to be.

However I'm having trouble simplifying the result of this integral.  All of those constants (wrt $x$) are getting crazy.

For instance just the part of the expression in the integrand that I've gotten so far (which is maybe half of the part without $x$ in it) is

$$\frac{\hbar^2 a(a^4-\hbar^2t^2/(4m^2)-i\hbar t/m)}{2\sqrt{2\pi}(a^4+\hbar^2t^2/4m^2)^2}$$

This seems way too complicated and I haven't even gotten to the point where I can take the integral yet (which incidentally should be the easiest part).  Mathematica isn't being especially useful at the moment in giving me shorter expressions.  I suspect it's because it assumes all variables are complex.  Is there some way to simplify all of this -- especially the complex algebra part -- that I'm missing?  Thanks.

BTW, all variables/ constants are real.  In fact all the constants ($a$, $\hbar$, and $m$) are positive real numbers and the variables $t$ and $x$ are real numbers.

---

**Edit:**

So setting

$$\Psi(x,t) = \frac{e^{-x^2/4(a^2+i\hbar t/2m)}}{\sqrt[4]{2\pi}\sqrt{a+i\hbar t/2ma}} = \frac{e^{-x^2/A}}{B},$$

evaluating the integral, and simplifying I'm getting

$$\frac{2\hbar^2}{|A|^2|B|^2}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}|A|\operatorname{Im}(A)\color{red}{iA^*}}{[\operatorname{Re}(A)]^{3/2}}$$

Before even plugging in my expressions for $A$ and $B$ I see something wrong: $-\hbar^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$ corresponds to an observable (momentum squared) and thus its expectation value *should be real*.  But all of the numbers in this last expression are real *except* the part in red which will be complex.  Thus I've made some mistake.

I can't see a mistake in my calculations.  Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: To any future interested readers, see how to work it out over at [physics.SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/277838/expectation-value-of-p2-coming-out-complex).

Answer (score 2):

Re-writhe $\Psi(x)=Ae^\frac {-x^2} s$, where $s=4(a^2+i\hbar t/2m)$ and $A=\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2\pi}\sqrt{a+i\hbar t/2ma}}$. Then $$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(\Psi(x))=\frac{-2A(s-2x^2)}{s^2}e^{\frac{-x^2}{s}}$$ Then expand $s$ and calculate $\Psi(x)^*$

The integral is standard then.